# Как разумнее: "прочь и замужъ" или "проч и замуж"?

Tags: орфография

Примечание

1. В выражении "прочь и замужъ" используются грамматический "ь" и грамматический "ъ", похожие на магнитные заряды "S" и "N".
2. В выражении "проч и замуж" не используются вышеупомянутые продукты воображения.

Comment: Не разумнее Ваших врачей, мышей, и котов. Ну зачем же пережёванное жевать?

Comment: Я не возражаю, чтобы Вы не жевали пережёванное что-то.

Answer (score 4):

Разумнее - не отвечать на такие вопросы.
Как правильнее - так и разумнее.
Другого критерия разумности нет.

Answer (score 3):

Вопрос состоит в том, что есть в русском языке четыре наречия, которые оканчиваются на щипящую Ж :
настежЬ,
уж,
замуж,
невтерпеж,
(+ устар. наречие однакож).

Почему три известных последних наречия принято писать без Ь, а *настежЬ* - с ним?
*Уж* - усеченное *уже*.
*За/муж* - производное от *муж* (сущ. м.р.)
*Не/в/терпеж* - производное от *терпеж* (то же самое).
*НастежЬ* - нельзя приписать к этим исключениям, оно (наречие) стремится к себе подобным, с окончанием на Ч/Ш : *прочь, вскачь, навзничь, наотмашь, наопашь, сплошь... В корнях которых произошло чередование (г-ж), к-ч, х-ш, ск-ш, и отдельных слов типа (*стеж), *скач, отмаш, плош* - не существует.
Почему вообще Ь пишется после шипящих во многих известных случаях? Старинная традиция.

Comment: 1. Спасибо за предоставленные  сведения, включая ответ на вопрос "Почему вообще Ь пишется после шипящих во многих известных случаях?".

2. Если у Вас будет время и желание, попытайтесь ответить на мой вопрос.

3. Я по-прежнему ценю Ваше мнение.

Answer (score 3):

Всё должно быть уместным, оправданным и необходимым, поэтому каждому вопросу свой форум!

А в формате нашего форума поговорим о том, почему в наречиях пишется мягкий знак после шипящих. Скорее всего, это их падежная форма, здесь мягкий знак - бывший редуцированный гласный, обозначающий падежное окончание, который, кстати, пишется и не только после шипящих, например: оземь, поодаль.

Но особый интерес представляет выбранное автором вопроса наречие "ПРОЧЬ", имеющее в нашем языке много неожиданных родственников: впрок (про запас), прочить (=предсказывать, предназначать), прочий (=другой), прочный (=крепкий). И я предлагаю всем (как  высоким гостям, так и участникам нашего форума) также попробовать "перейти за грань",   послушав особое звучание этих слов и вернув им  свежесть их изначального образа.

Представьте себе предлог ПРО как нечто обращенное в будущее, устремленное вперед. Тогда прокъ - это некий сохраненный на будущее остаток/предмет.

От него образовано прилагательное "ПРОЧИЙ" - оставшийся на будущее (только потом - остальной). А прилагательное ПРОЧНЫЙ -  это подходящий для "прочего" (только потом крепкий).

ПРОЧИТЬ - сначала "оставлять на будущее", а потом (перенос по смежности) - предсказывать будущее.

И наконец, наш герой, наречие "прочь", которое в наибольшей степени несет в себе значение предлога ПРО. Прочь - это сравнительная степень от "прочий", буквально: "прочее", дальше, вперед до ближайшего будущего, вон.

Возможно, что, прочитав этот небольшой рассказ, вы согласитесь со мной: надо дать возможность слову "прочь" , как и всем другим словам, иметь свою историю, записанную в буквах.

Comment: Милая София.

Ваш ответ похож на школьное сочинение.

Comment: А  мне  понравился.

Comment: >Ваш ответ похож на школьное сочинение.  
  
Ваш вопрос похож на троллинг.